# different rules for the same AR model in Yii

Tags: php, mongodb, activerecord, yii, yii-validation

I have one model extending AR class with specific rules. But now i need to insert row into this table, but with other rules. Is i need to create other model with new rules, or it is possible to define orther rules?

Answer (score 5):

You can set validation scenario. For example:

```
$model = new Post(); 
$model->scenario = 'new_line';
$model->attributes = $_GET['data'];
if ($model->validate()){
    $model->save(false);
}
```

in your model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('username, text', 'required','on' => 'new_line')
    );
}
```

In model rules all array lines must have key "on", else this rules will not apply.

Read more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/).

Comment: To make it shorter, you can even do $model = new Post('new_line');

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending your class (active records) then you can actually just override your rules() function i.e.:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord(){
    function rules(){
        return array(array(
            // Nomrally a rule
        ))
    }
}
```

And then make your next class:

```
class User_extended extends ActiveRecord(){
    function rules(){
        return array(array(
            // Nomrally a rule
        ))
    }
}
```

And that should be it. You can then call the `User_extended` class and your rules will apply to the parent `User` class since Yii grabs the rules in a `$this` context and `$this` will be your child class.

But you can also use scenarios here, but it might get dirty especially if you need to override other methods.

Answer (score 0):

thx. Now i'm trying to use this

```
/**
 * @param string $attribute fields names wich should be validated
 * @param array $params additional params for validation
 */
public function ValidatorName($attribute,$params) { … }
```

Comment: If your not using scenarios You'll need to bind it still, if on `beforeValidate` you bind it you should be fine.